# How to specify nothrow exception specifier for destructor?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, nothrow

I am trying to specify that a function is `nothrow` whenever the destructor of `Foo` doesn't throw. I can do this by using the type trait `std::is_nothrow_destructible<>`. How can I do this directly? I've tried the following, but it doesn't compile if I uncomment the commented line

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Foo
{
public:
    ~Foo() noexcept {}
};

// void f() noexcept(noexcept(~Foo{})) { } // error here
void g() noexcept(std::is_nothrow_destructible<Foo>::value) 
{

}

int main()
{
    g();
}
```

I get an error

```
 error: no match for 'operator~' (operand type is 'Foo')
```

The error specifier `noexcept(noexcept(~Foo()))` is not OK, although for constructors I can use `noexcept(noexcept(Foo()))`. Am I missing some obvious syntax here?

Comment: A destructor should never throw an exception.

Comment: Destructors are implicitly `noexcept(true)`, so there's no need to add a user defined destructor only for the `noexcept` specification.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes I know this, I was just messing around with `nothrow` and bumped into this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Destructors can only be called through a member access expression. So the syntax would be:

```
void f() noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<Foo>().~Foo()))
```

Comment: Perfect! It works. Why is this asymmetry between constructors and destructors? Is it because in principle you don't "manually" invoke the destructor?

Comment: The asymmetry is because for `noexcept(expr)`, `expr` has to be a valid expression.  `Foo()` is a valid expression that could occur outside of a `noexcept` specifier, but `~Foo()` is not.  You can, however, write `Foo f; f.~Foo()`, which is effectively what this answer does.

Comment: @TavianBarnes the `declval` doesn't create any temporary though, it uses an unevaluated expression.

Comment: @vsoftco I believe it's because the syntax `~Foo()` is ambiguous between a destructor call and a user-defined `operator~()` being called on a temporary `Foo` instance.

Comment: @0x499602D2 The bigger problem is "what is `~Foo()` supposed to destroy?"

Comment: @vsoftco A constructor creates a new instance, a destructor must be invoked on an existing instance. The `declval` expression provides this instance (without actually creating one).

Comment: @T.C. That's a better way of phrasing it.  Destructors are not any different than other member functions in this sense.

Comment: @0x499602D2: I don't think it's *ambiguous*... `~Foo()` is unambiguously negation of a default-constructed `Foo`, as the destructor's only considered when there's member-function call syntax ala `a_foo.~Foo()`.

Comment: @TonyD He's asking why there's a difference between a constructor and destructor call. If a destructor could be called like `~Foo()` then it would be ambiguous with the negation syntax. T.C. gave a good reason why it isn't allowed.